# Ubuntu boots w/o gui on tty1 w/o network

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments

I am working on ubuntu 20.04. For some resons after a reboot it started booting on tty1 without any GUI nor network connection.

I have read about a similar issue on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/65185/when-i-start-ubuntu-it-enters-tty1-6-instead-of-my-desktop-how-do-i-get-to-de

My hypothesis is that I have inadvertently uninstalled my desktop environement. However it would seem that my network is not working either, despite beeing physically connected to a working network (I checked cables).

When I try to ping anything I get:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network iy unreachable
```

Which also means that I can't do a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Because I get

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/...
```

I'm looking for help on why this is happening, how I can confirm that the accidental uninstallation of the desktop environement is indeed the cause and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your networking stack is still installed, you should be able to change your network settings by running `nmtui` in the TTY - this will give you a graphical-looking menu where you can fiddle with your networking settings. From here you can activate whatever networking device connects your system to the Internet. (This works even with WiFi.)

Once connected, you should be able to use `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and see if anything needs reinstalled.

Comment: Ok so it seems my problem was a bit deeper. Apparently I lost a bunch of packages and I had to spend some time downloading and re installing them. However once this was done this absolutely did the trick. Great answer